# Eclipse RCP - can I open an editor in a background thread?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is this possible? Because our editor does a lot of rights management/webservice stuff and awfully slow and blocks the UI thread completely. I'd like to get back to the main thread only after everything is ready.

I'm not sure if its possible with Eclipse's own multi-editor based editors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial load of the editor part must run in the UI thread.

You could then use a `Job` or some other background thread to finish initializing the editor data.

The background code must use `Display.asyncExec` to execute code in the UI thread.